# How is this file being passed in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

I run this program which has this run command:

```
gzip -dc file.gz | java driver
```

Can someone explain how this works (how is this file.gz being passed to the java program) and how can I do this using Netbeans.

Regards!

Comment: How can I do this using Netbeans? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer: the other way round: file.gz is uncompre4ssed to stdout and this is passed on as the input to stdin of the java process running the driver program.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I knew it was piping somewhere :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe `|` in linux is a convenience for redirecting output of a program to input of another.

For example suppose you're trying to locate a file with name `java` in current directory. Then `ls -l` will list the file but to do the second part we can just pipe this output to `grep` like below.

```
ls -l | grep java
```

If it were not so, then we would have to first save the output of `ls -l` into a file then use that file with `grep` to search.

Same is happening in your example `gzip -dc`.

```
-d stands for decompress
-c output to the console (not a file)
```

Now since gzip output (binary output) is dumped on the console we can use pipe to feed to Java program.

In `java driver` driver is an executable JAR file (without extension `.jar` in your case). `driver` JAR has a main method which receives command line arguments.

Now driver's main method is expecting the binary content to it's command line input parameter (`main(String[] args)`, where `args` is array of command line parameters).

If you want to use this utility for your project then you have to somehow decompress the `gzip` file using Java and then store the output in a String and pass it to the driver's main method.

```
String gzipStr = ... extract gzip as string
com.example.DriverMain.main({gzipStr});//suppose that main method is in com.example.DriverMain class
```

You can find the main class by looking at the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` content inside the driver JAR.